# Nuxt3 and Cloudinary Upload API: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Tags: cloudinary, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use the [Cloudinary Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_required_parameters) to programmatically upload a File object to my Cloudinary media library, but for some reason I get the following server error:

```js
{
    "url": "/api/cloudinary/upload",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "statusMessage": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object",
    "description": "<pre><span class=\"stack internal\">at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at basename (node:path:752:5)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at post // snipped out rest
```

**Am I not setting up the folder path correctly here or is something else the problem?**

I am using the following code (in my NuxtJS app):

`components/UserProfileAvatar.vue`:

```js
const file = ref(null)

const handleAvatarUpload = async (e) => {
  file.value = e.target.files[0]

  // Upload file to Cloudinary and get public_id
  const options = {
    public_id: 'profile-image',
    folder: `users/${userStore.userProfile.uid}/avatar/` 
  }

  try {
    const response = await $fetch('/api/cloudinary/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        options: options,
        file: file.value
      }
    })
    console.log('Uploaded!', response.asset)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error uploading file', error)
  }
}
```

If I console log the logic above, I get the following output:

[image]

**Anyone spot anything as to why I get the the error "The Path argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object"** in my original attempt?

Comment: Maybe try it with Postman first. Otherwise, the API is indeed probably receiving an object in one of the arguments that you are sending.

Comment: Not too familiar with Postman but i will try. thanks

Comment: I was looking at network tab for the browser and it says the payload for the file is an empty object. Is that normal for security reasons or am I really missing the file?

Comment: OK I console logged the nuxt server api route and it is indeed an empty file object being passed....but not sure why the client console log shows the File exists....I will show my server api code in the above question for more details

Comment: I had to wrap the file in a promise and use FileReader API to get it to work. All good now.